# Chrome Mobile: window.open starts up a Chrome PWA instead of opening a new browser tab

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-chrome, progressive-web-app

I have a PWA which, most of the time, I tend to use in-browser.

In **Firefox Mobile**, I can click on a `<button>` to execute `window.open` which then opens a **new tab** in the browser, displaying custom content.

The `<button>` behaves identically in both **Firefox Desktop** and **Chrome Desktop**.

Opening a new browser tab is the desired behaviour

Only this morning I discovered that clicking on that `<button>` in **Chrome Mobile** (84.0.4147.105) opens a new PWA instance, outside the browser, instead.

Is there any Chrome Mobile setting I can change (or any alternative approach I can adopt) to ensure that when I click the `<button>` in Chrome Mobile, it opens a **new browser tab** (as it does in all the other browsers)?

Comment: It looks fine to me.   We typically close questions about phone apps, but this appears to be about using a website on the phone rather than an installed app on the phone.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenOstermiller.

Comment: Similar question from March 2020, 5 months ago: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554479/pwa-force-window-open-to-open-browser-instead-of-pwa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554479/pwa-force-window-open-to-open-browser-instead-of-pwa) - albeit, it comes with a pretty elaborate workaround solution and not one I'm inclined to adopt.

Comment: Yes, I seem to be running into trouble trying to implement 2FA now. `ExternalLoginSigninAsync` is being called from **external.example.com**, and `TwoFactorAuthenticatorSigninAsync` is being called from **example.com**. But this causes 2FA to fail since they must be called from the same domain.